# Automatically populating HTML attributes with Django for-loop

Tags: html, django, wagtail

I am making a website using Django and Wagtail CMS, and have a way of filtering posts by a custom attribute called "data-group" in the html template. It works when I hard-code everything, but I would like to use some logic to have that attribute filled dynamically for each post. Basically, I want the post tags to be populated there, but I am having a problem doing this.

I will highlight relevant lines of the code with

```
--------------------------
```

An example of hard-coded filter buttons:

```
 <ul class="portfolio-filters">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="category_all">All</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data group="category_detailed">Detailed</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="category_direct-url">Direct URL</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="category_image">Image</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="category_soundcloud">SoundCloud</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="category_video">Video</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="category_vimeo-video">Vimeo Video</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="category_youtube-video">YouTube Video</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

When any of the above buttons are clicked, it filters posts/items with similar values in the data-group attribute.

An example of the items it is filtering are below in the figure data-groups list:

```
 --------------------------<figure class="item standard" data-groups='["category_all", "category_detailed"]'> --------------------------
                      <div class="item">
                        <div class="blog-card">
                          <div class="media-block">
                            <div class="category">
                              <a href="#" title="View all posts in WordPress">WordPress</a>
                            </div>
                            <a href="blog-post-1.html">
                              <img src="./img/blog/blog_post_1.jpg" alt="How to Make a WordPress Plugin Extensible" title="" />
                              <div class="mask"></div>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="post-info">
                            <div class="post-date">04 Dec 2019</div>
                            <a href="blog-post-1.html">
                              <h4 class="blog-item-title">How to Make a WordPress Plugin Extensible</h4>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </figure>
```

More examples that match the above buttons:

```
<figure class="item lbvideo" data-groups='["category_all", "category_video", "category_youtube-video"]'>
<figure class="item lbimage" data-groups='["category_all", "category_image"]'>
<figure class="item lbaudio" data-groups='["category_all", "category_soundcloud"]'>
<figure class="item lbvideo" data-groups='["category_all", "category_video", "category_vimeo-video"]'>
```

etc...

The above works when everything is hard coded as above.

However, I want to create a single template through a for loop that will be populated with each added post/portfolio item, and so I have tried some logic that populates the filters, but I can't seem to grab the tags and insert them into the data-groups attribute in the figures.

The below works to populate the buttons (although I haven't found a way to display just the unique items here):

```
{% for post in all_posts %}
                        {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                        <li>
                            <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="{{tag}}">{{tag}}</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is my code for populating the post tags in the attributes, which doesn't seem to be working:

```
{% for post in all_posts %}
                                <!-- Blog Post 1 -->
       --------------------------<figure class="item standard" data-group='["all", {% for tag in post.tags.all %}tag{% endfor %} ]'>-------------------------------
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <div class="blog-card">
                                            <div class="media-block">
                                                <div class="category">
                                                    <a href="#" title="View all posts in WordPress">WordPress</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <a href="blog-post-1.html">
                                                    {% image post.blog_image fill-350x200 as img %}
                                                    <img src="{{img.url}}" alt="{{img.alt}}" title="">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="post-info">
                                                <div class="post-date">{{post.published_date}}</div>
                                                <br>
                                                {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                                                <div class="post-date">{{tag}},</div> <!-- This populates fine! -->
                                                {% endfor %}
                                                <a href="blog-post-1.html">
                                                    <h4 class="blog-item-title">{{post.custom_title}}</h4>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </figure>
                                {% endfor %}
```

Does anybody know a way to populate that attribute with items from the model automatically, so as to avoid having to hard-code in HTML?

This code works fine to populate text, such as the below which displays fine:

```
{% for tag in post.tags.all %}
      <div class="post-date">{{tag}},</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks.

Edit: Adding photos of behaviour.

When I click "all", all posts appear as below (I have highlighted the filters populated through tags in the top right, and under each post is the programmatically added tag for that post):

[image: All images are shown when no filters, or the "all" filter is clicked]

When I click any other filter, they all disappear:
[image: Posts disappear when filtered by anything but "all"]
Clicking any other filter, they all disappear, despite printing the tags below them.

Edit 2: Adding the inspects of the actual pages.
This is the html of the populated figures when inspected, which as far as I am aware, has the correct items populated and formatted:
[image]

These are the filter buttons with their data-groups automatically generated when inspected:
[image]

This is the javascript that filters the page:
[image]

Comment: Rather than just saying that your template code "doesn't seem to be working", it would be helpful to tell us the HTML it produces, and how that differs from the expected output.

Comment: Added some photos to illustrate the issue I am having.

Comment: Rather than trying to diagnose the issue from images: try looking at the generated HTML source, in your browser's developer tools, and see how it differs from the HTML of your working hard-coded version. That will almost certainly tell you everything you need to fix the problem yourself - and if not, show us the two versions side by side and we can tell you what needs to be fixed in the Django template code to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just missing `{{ }}` brackets around `tag`, so it's just outputting the literal text `tag` rather than your `tag` variable. You'll also need to ensure the commas and quotes are in the right places...

```
data-group='["all"{% for tag in post.tags.all %}, "{{ tag }}"{% endfor %} ]'
```

Or if you need the `category_` prefixes as in your working example:

```
data-group='["category_all"{% for tag in post.tags.all %}, "category_{{ tag }}"{% endfor %} ]'
```

Comment: Hi gasman, thanks for the note, I had completely forgot about that despite doing it everywhere else lol.
However, even after adding it, the problem still persists. Basically, when I click any of the filters, if I click "all", they all appear (as all is hard-coded), but none of the other filters seem to be working - all items disappear despite their filters in the data-group.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, a combination of gasman's formatting suggestion, as well as making the data-group plural for the post solved the issue.

From:

```
<figure class="item standard" data-group='["all"{% for tag in post.tags.all %},"{{tag}}"{% endfor %}]'>
```

To:

```
<figure class="item standard" data-groups='["all"{% for tag in post.tags.all %},"{{tag}}"{% endfor %}]'>
```

To anybody having a similar issue, just a note that the placement of the commas is very important. When trouble-shooting through hard-coding, if I had an inappropriate comma at the beginning or end of the list, the code wouldn't work.